# Which template file extension provides support for Rails 7.1 and turbo-frames?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I can't seem to get the correct format of data returned to the browser for turbo processing.

app/views/the_form.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "dog_quick_search" do %>
    <% form_tag quick_search_via_form_dogs_path(format: :turbo_stream) do %>
    blah
    blah
    <%= submit_tag('Go', class: 'btn-warning') %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/dogs_controller.rb

```
def quick_search_via_form
    do stuff...
    render 'xxxx'
end
```

app/views/dogs/xxxx.....

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "dog_quick_search" do %>
  Bring back ujs
<% end %>
```

Based upon the file extensions of xxxx I get:

xxxx.html.erb:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template dogs/xxxx, application/xxxx with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:turbo_stream], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

xxx.erb:

```
The contents of xxxx.erb replace the entire webpage in the browser
```

xxx.turbo-stream.html.erb

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template dogs/xxxx, application/xxxx with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:turbo_stream], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

From reading around Turbo it seemed that all I had to do was have matching turbo-frame id in source and rendered template, with an extension of the usual .html.erb and it would replace the turbo-frame with the content of the one returned.
As I'm unable to return the .html.erb template I'm wondering if that's the issue but can't see how to stop the error regarding not being able to find that particular template.

## Update:

By adding an explicit format to the render instruction it works:

```
render 'xxxx' formats: :html
```

I don't understand this to be honest - if the template has the extension .html.erb surely that tells rails that it's an html template as it used to do in previous rails versions?

Comment: The issue seems to stem from the form submit not being intercepted by turbo but I've no idea why not.

Answer (score 1):

> all I had to do was have matching turbo-frame id

That's exactly what you need to do, but you probably want to keep your form outside of the frame:

```rb
# app/views/the_form.html.erb

# don't add `format: :turbo_stream`
<%= form_with url: quick_search_via_form_dogs_path, method: :get,
  data: {turbo_frame: :dog_quick_search} do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :search %>
  <%= f.submit "Go", class: "btn-warning" %>
<% end %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "dog_quick_search", data: {turbo_action: :advance} %>
```

```rb
# app/controllers/dogs_controller.rb

def quick_search_via_form
  render "search"
end
```

```rb
# app/views/dogs/search.html.erb

<%= turbo_frame_tag "dog_quick_search" do %>
  <%= params[:search] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've made the changes you suggested but it appears that the form is now being submitted as HTML rather than a TURBO-STREAM as previously. This is resulting in the entire page being rendered and overwritten in the browser.

Comment: @Houdi "HTML rather than a TURBO-STREAM" - it doesn't matter we're not using turbo stream here. turbo stream and turbo frame are two separate and independent concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The issue was determined to be that the form submit wasn't being intercepted by Turbo.

This was because bootstrap needed to be pinned by running

```
$ bin/importmap pin bootstrap
```

Now the form is being submitted as a TURBO-STREAM. The tag content isn't being replaced mind but thats an issue for tomorrow!